# Dynamic validation in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a[rel=addhint]').click(function(){
  var html='<div><label>Hint</label>';
  html+='<span class="input"><input type="text" size="30" class="text" name="hint"/><a href="#" rel="delhint">delete</a></span><br class="clear" /></div>';
  $('div#hintTextContainer').append(html);
  bindDelHintAll();
  return false;
 });
```

I want when a new text area include vadition of required field and max length will also apply on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code you are dynamically building a form in the duration of a page view. In order to on-the-fly implement a form validation system you would need the function which creates the input to have a way to plug into the form validation system.

One solution would be to add an attribute to the field which would be read by the validation function.

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="hint" validation-params='{ "req" : true, "max-length" : 10 }'>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#testform").submit(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      self.find("input").each(function() {
        var validation = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).attr("validation-params"));
        if (validation.req) { alert("required"); }
      }); 
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

If you look at the example above, you'll see that it creates a form. In the submit handler it takes the form and loops through every input on the form and grabs the validation-params attribute and converts the string attribute to a JSON object. It then checks a specific field, you could easily add your own validation to it right there.

Comment: basically i have a this reference <a href="#" rel="addhint">Add Hint</a>
in my page to call the dynamic create text field.
but every time name of created field is hint.
i want to put checks on this newly created field using java script.
as  frmvalidator.addValidation("hint","req");   
          frmvalidator.addValidation("hint","maxlen=100");
but because every time name is hint therefore check does not apply.
how differ the newlly created text field
or how assaign adifferent name.

Comment: Usually, no two input fields should share a name. So you should create an iterator. In example, lets imagine you added a class="hintfield". You could do a hintfields = $("#formid").find(".hintfield").length to get the number of hint fields and then make the name of the field being created equal to hint_ & hintfields + 1.

But really, I think the best way would be to add an attribute, it's a more OO solution. validation-params="{ req: true,max-length: 100}"

Comment: validation-params="{ max-length: 10, min-length: 0}"
not work

Comment: I edited my example above with a working code sample. Hope it helps Mansoor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are familiar with the jQuery validation plugin
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

It is a very robust library, all sorts of goodies. It may be overkill for the example you have put forth. It does not have a lot about dynamically added content but you may be able to tweak the framework to do what you want.

Aside from that. There is also a really great textarea maxlength plugin, so you won't even have to validate it!
http://sigswitch.com/2010/04/updated-textarea-maxlength-with-jquery-plugin/

As far as making sure the user has content in the text area, just check

```
jQuery('textarea.newlyAdded').val().lenght > 0
```

when submitting.

Comment: basically i have a this reference <a href="#" rel="addhint">Add Hint</a>
in my page to call the dynamic create text field.
but every time name of created field is hint.
i want to put checks on this newly created field using java script.
as  frmvalidator.addValidation("hint","req");   
          frmvalidator.addValidation("hint","maxlen=100");
but because every time name is hint therefore check does not apply.
how differ the newlly created text field
or how assaign adifferent name.